# Stripe layout ios keyboard hide by default.

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe SDK which creates a view for card details. The code is as follows:

```
//live key
NSString *cardApiKey;

if([hostType isEqualToString:@"production"])
{
    cardApiKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
} else {
    cardApiKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}

self.stripeView = [[STPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, _cardDetailsLabel.frame.origin.y+_cardDetailsLabel.frame.size.height+10, 200, 55) andKey:cardApiKey];

[self.canvasView addSubview:self.stripeView];

self.stripeView.delegate = self;
```

The problem is that the number pad keyboard shows by default. I do not want the numberpad keyboard to pop up everytime i init the stripeview. How can I get around this? Thanks.

Comment: It shows the number keyboard because when you initialize, the focus directly goes to the Credit card number textField. This is the default behaviour. Do you want the textField not to gain focus when  the STPView is shown?

Comment: yes that is correct. how can I do that?

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Nope I never found a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 1: Using custom views**

You could use custom views rather than STPView which would give you full control over when the keyboard is triggered. You can then just populate an instance of STPCart. The stripe gighub page describes this approach under the section: **'using your own views'**.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios

```
STPCard *card = [[STPCard alloc] init];
card.number = @"4242424242424242";
card.expMonth = 12;
card.expYear = 2020;
```

---

**Approach 2: Using Stripes STPView implementation**

To do it with Stripe's STPView you can use an approach using addTarget on the offending UITextField subclass for the UIControlEventEditingDidBegin event. You can remove it after the view loads as it's no longer required:

```
// YourViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "YourViewController.h"

@class STPView;

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) STPView *stripeView;

@end

// YourViewController.m

#import "YourViewController.h"
#import "STPView.h"
#import "PKView.h"
#import "PKTextField.h"

@interface YourViewController ()
@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create your STPView instance
    _stripeView = [[STPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,20,290,55) andKey:@"perishable_key"];
    [self.view addSubview:_stripeView];
    // Add target for editingDidBegin UIControl event
    [_stripeView.paymentView.cardNumberField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingBegan:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
}

- (void)editingBegan:(id)sender
{
    // Hide the keyboard
    [_stripeView.paymentView.cardNumberField resignFirstResponder];
    // Remove the addTarget
    [_stripeView.paymentView.cardNumberField removeTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
}

@end
```

**cardNumberField** is an instance of PKTextField (a subclass of UITextField) and the view that gets the focus when the STPView is created.

Comment: I know I can do this but I really like stripes implementation. it is a beautifully formed card details entry group of textfields. Is there really know way to stop it from forcing itself to open?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my answer to make it a bit clearer, approach 2 uses the Stripe STPView, which is the grouped textfields that you describe.

Comment: Cool I will try this out when I complete this next trello ticket thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

So, As mentioned in the comment, the behaviour is that the focus automatically goes to the STPView's creditCard textField when it gets initialized. Hence, the keyboard gets triggered when the focus is in the textField. So, the workaround should be that we need to make the textField lose focus when it is added to the view. Try like this:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.stripeView endEditing:YES]; //This sets whatever textFields inside (though we have only one) lose focus when the self.stripeView added to its parentView.
}
```